# When/why do I need to make/install linux headers?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, compiling

The use case is installing Ubuntu Core to run as an appliance. The machine:

- will run a **single task**,
- is preferably slimmed down to have **low disk space** consumption,
- has the (custom) kernel installed via a **.deb** file (not the "linux" meta package)

The kernel compile `make-kpkg` command suggest to include `kernel_headers`.

But *why* and/or *when* do I really need (or is it wise) to make and/or install linux headers (package)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the linux headers when you plan to **develop and compile** on the machine where you've installed Ubuntu.

If you build an appliance dedicated to a specific task, you are certainly not willing to compile on it.

If you need to compile your own application, you will do this on an different system. A development one and copy the compiled code to the appliance.

Comment: If I use the machine for java application development, can I delete them?

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of this tool and suggest you follow the
[Kernel Team documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) for building a kernel from source.

Installing kernel-headers never hurts and is required for any build
from source driver provided by a dkms package.